# SharpSVN: Check if the checkout URI is valid or not

Tags: c#, sharpsvn, svn-checkout

I am using sharpSVN to programatically perform tasks such as Checkingout and committing.
The user enters the URI to checkout and presses Checkout button.

A lot of times user enters invalid URI and when the program attempts to checkout, it throws an exception. I can handle the exception but I want to check if URI is valid before even attempting to checkout.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest SvnClient command to verify the server status would be to call `SvnClient.Info()` on the Uri. If the target is a directory (check `.Kind`) you can safely use `.CheckOut()`.